# Synonyms for the word “secret”

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, synonyms

I’m looking for synonyms that mean the word “secret”, as in a PERSONAL secret.

e.g (3):

I whispered my secrets to her.

I have a secret to tell you.

I have a lot of secrets that i’m holding on to.

Comment: What synonyms have you found that don't fit the bill?  Please include your research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dictionary.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/secret):

- code
- confidential information
- key
- mystery
- cipher
- confidence
- enigma
- formula
- occult
- oracle
- password
- puzzle

Comment: Thank you so much, especially for the various answers. Helps a lot. :)